# Deal with the help message using boost program_options, removing default values or reformatting the help message

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am writing a C++ program involving boost::program_options, here I came across some problems. Some of my codes are given here.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    options_description desc("useage: filterfq", options_description::m_default_line_length * 2, options_description::m_default_line_length);

    options_description generic("Gerneric options", options_description::m_default_line_length * 2, options_description::m_default_line_length);
    generic.add_options()
        ("help,h", "produce help message")
    ;

    options_description param("Parameters", options_description::m_default_line_length * 2, options_description::m_default_line_length);
    param.add_options()
        ("checkQualitySystem,c", bool_switch(), "only check quality system of the fastq file")
        ("baseNrate,N", value<float>() -> default_value(0.05), "maximum rate of \'N\' base allowed along a read")
        ("averageQuality,Q", value<float>() -> default_value(0), "minimum average quality allowed along a read")
        ("perBaseQuality,q", value<int>() -> default_value(5), "minimum quality per base allowed along a read")
        ("lowQualityRate,r", value<float>() -> default_value(0.5), "maximum low quality rate along a read")
        ("rawQualitySystem,s", value<int>(), "specify quality system of raw fastq\n0: Sanger\n1: Solexa\n2: Illumina 1.3+\n3: Illumina 1.5+\n4: Illumina 1.8+")
        ("preferSpecifiedRawQualitySystem,p", bool_switch(), "indicate that user prefers the given quality system to process")
    ;

    options_description input("Input", options_description::m_default_line_length * 2, options_description::m_default_line_length);
    input.add_options()
        ("rawFastq,f", value< vector<path> >() -> required() -> multitoken(), "raw fastq file(s) that need cleaned, required")
    ;

    options_description output("Output", options_description::m_default_line_length * 2, options_description::m_default_line_length);
    output.add_options()
        ("cleanQualitySystem,S", value<int>() -> default_value(4), "specify quality system of cleaned fastq, the same as rawQualitySystem")
        ("outDir,O", value<path>() -> default_value(current_path()), "specify output directory, not used if cleanFastq is specified")
        ("outBasename,o", value<string>(), "specify the basename for output file(s), required if outDir is specified")
        ("cleanFastq,F", value< vector<path> >() -> multitoken(), "cleaned fastq file name(s), not used if outDir or outBasename is specified")
        ("droppedFastq,D", value< vector<path> >() -> multitoken(), "fastq file(s) containing reads that are filtered out")
    ;

    desc.add(generic).add(param).add(input).add(output);

    variables_map vm;
    store(command_line_parser(argc, argv).options(desc).run(), vm);
    if (vm.count("help")) {
        cout << desc << "\n";
        return 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

The #include using namespace parts are not given here. When I typed the command to see the help message, it showed me the following

```
useage: filterfq:

Gerneric options:
  -h [ --help ]         produce help message

Parameters:
  -c [ --checkQualitySystem ]               only check quality system of the fastq file
  -N [ --baseNrate ] arg (=0.0500000007)    maximum rate of 'N' base allowed along a read
  -Q [ --averageQuality ] arg (=0)          minimum average quality allowed along a read
  -q [ --perBaseQuality ] arg (=5)          minimum quality per base allowed along a read
  -r [ --lowQualityRate ] arg (=0.5)        maximum low quality rate along a read
  -s [ --rawQualitySystem ] arg             specify quality system of raw fastq
                                            0: Sanger
                                            1: Solexa
                                            2: Illumina 1.3+
                                            3: Illumina 1.5+
                                            4: Illumina 1.8+
  -p [ --preferSpecifiedRawQualitySystem ]  indicate that user prefers the given quality system to process

Input:
  -f [ --rawFastq ] arg raw fastq file(s) that need cleaned, required

Output:
  -S [ --cleanQualitySystem ] arg (=4)             specify quality system of cleaned fastq, the same as rawQualitySystem
  -O [ --outDir ] arg (="/home/tanbowen/filterfq") specify output directory, not used if cleanFastq is specified
  -o [ --outBasename ] arg                         specify the basename for output file(s), required if outDir is specified
  -F [ --cleanFastq ] arg                          cleaned fastq file name(s), not used if outDir or outBasename is specified
  -D [ --droppedFastq ] arg                        fastq file(s) containing reads that are filtered out
```

The help message looks somewhat ugly, especially the "0.0500000007", I want to improve it. But I googled for a long time, I cannot find solutions. So I ask for help here solve following problems:

1. **Is there any method to reformat the help message?**
2. **If 1 is not possible, how to drop out the part of "arg" and default values?**
3. **And is there any way to align the right-hand descriptions?**

One extra question: how can I prevent the following command to be executed

```
filter -f <some file> -f <some file>
```

i.e., do not allow the same option to be specified more than once?

Thanks very much!!

Comment: if you search carefully in the program_options documentation it mentions making a custom class to receive option values. You write operator<< and operator>> for this class. Then you can format it as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, see below (shows the general form of collecting and displaying formatted options)
2. look at the constructor of `options_description`. It allows you to specify column widths.

Here is a (real) example of a custom option value. In my case I wanted to collect a buffer size in bytes, but also wanted to be able to parse things like 4K or 1M.

```
struct bytesize_option
{
    bytesize_option(std::size_t val = 0) : _size(val) {}

    std::size_t value() const { return _size; }
    void set(std::size_t val) { _size = val; }

private:
    std::size_t _size;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, bytesize_option const& hs);
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bytesize_option& hs);

namespace {
    static constexpr auto G = std::size_t(1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    static constexpr auto M = std::size_t(1024 * 1024);
    static constexpr auto K = std::size_t(1024);
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, bytesize_option const& hs)
{
    auto v = hs.value();
    if (v % G == 0) { return os << (v / G) << 'G'; }
    if (v % M == 0) { return os << (v / M) << 'M'; }
    if (v % K == 0) { return os << (v / K) << 'K'; }
    return os << v;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, bytesize_option& hs)
{
    std::string s;
    is >> s;
    static const std::regex re(R"regex((\d+)([GMKgmk]){0,1})regex");
    std::smatch match;
    auto matched = std::regex_match(s, match, re);
    if(!matched) {
        throw po::validation_error(po::validation_error::invalid_option_value);
    }
    if (match[2].matched)
    {
        switch (match[2].str().at(0))
        {
            case 'G':
            case 'g':
                hs.set(std::stoul(match[1].str()) * G);
                break;
            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                hs.set(std::stoul(match[1].str()) * M);
                break;
            case 'K':
            case 'k':
                hs.set(std::stoul(match[1].str()) * K);
                break;
        }
    }
    else {
        hs.set(std::stoul(match[1].str()));
    }
    return is;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
    return boost::shared_ptr<po::option_description> {
        new po::option_description("server.max-header-size,x",
                                   po::value(&_max_hdr_size)
                                   ->default_value(_max_hdr_size),
                                   "The maximum size (in bytes) of a HTTP header "
                                   "that the server will accept")
    };
```

Where in this case, `_max_hdr_size` is defined:

```
bytesize_option _max_hdr_size;
```

Comment: I have tried to give two arguments related to column width in the options_description constructor as in the codes given above, but it does not work. It still does not align.